# Feign client name within RequestInterceptor

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

I have a feign client

```
@FeignClient(name = "client1")
public interface Client1 {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    HelloResponse hello();
}
```

How can I get the name `client1` within `RequestInterceptor`?

```
public class HelloInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        // how to get "client1" here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
requestTemplate.feignTarget().name()
```

This will give the client name

Comment: I don't see such a method.Which version are you using?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign/2.2.2.RELEASE